# Shelving files and then importing later on in SVN

Tags: svn

I have written a piece of code and now I want to send it out for review.
The problem is that, the reviewer is in a different time zone and it's impossible to sit together at the same time for review.
I worked on perforce earlier where I could shelve changes, give the reviewer changelist number and the reviewer could just import that change list into his workspace and thus my changes would land in his respective java files. Now he could not only review but also run my code. 
But currently I am using SVN and I am unable to find such option.
The maximum I could achieve was something called patch, which would list down all the changes in a notepad file, but this is the worst solution ever.
Is there a way, where I can create a copy of all the files I select , which has all the changes and can be imported by anyone directly in his/her project in java files in  SVN.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box shelving feature in subversion . The closest solution I can think about are

- Make a new Branch out of your local copy. Your reviewer can then merge the branch into his/her local copy.
- Patching.

2nd one is the most simple and straightforward one. A couple of commands will do the trick.

```
from your local copy
svn diff -c1234 > 1234.diff

from reviewers local copy

svn patch /path/to/diff/file/1234.diff
```

I've tried it a couple of time and it worked like a charm.

svn has some nice documentation regarding the same

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.patch.html